# Make a wavy red underline for some words in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, html, underline

I'm making a code editor and I'm trying to dynamicaly add a red wavy underline if user makes a mistake in code he's writing. I've tried to use **underlineSpan** but i don't see how to make it wavy. Changing color with .setColor() doesn't seem to work either. Is there a **Span** that can help me, or is there a way to achieve that with **Paint** ?

Comment: I've achieved this with writing a custom span, see solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27270036/519995

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll try to implement it later and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TextPaint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html#TextPaint%28android.graphics.Paint%29).

```
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
tp.linkColor = Color.BLACK;  //you can use your color using Color.parseColor("#123456");   
UnderlineSpan us = new UnderlineSpan();
us.updateDrawState(tp);
SpannableString sp = new SpannableString("Welcome to android");
sp.setSpan(us, 11, 18, 0); // UnderlineSpan Object, Start position, End position, Flag.
et.setText(sp);
```

This works for me. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unforunately this doesn't change color of underline for me.

Comment: Can you show me little bit of your code where you try to use underlinespan?

Comment: `Spannable span = new SpannableString(codeField.getText());
    TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
    tp.linkColor = Color.parseColor("#FF0000"); 
    UnderlineSpan undrlspan = new UnderlineSpan();
    undrlspan.updateDrawState(tp);
    span.setSpan(undrlspan, start, end,   Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    codeField.setText(span);`

Sorry for this formatting. First time writing question here. Where codeField is EditText containing user code.

Comment: I've checked, the color of textPaint have changed to red, but it has no effect on the underline itself